# How to detect if iframe video ends using Youtube API?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, youtube-api

I would like to know how can I detect when iframe video ends using youtube API.
I have managed to print the duration of the video using this script:

```
    $dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=" . $video_id['v'] . "&key=" . $key);

$duration =json_decode($dur, true);
foreach ($duration['items'] as $vidTime) {
    $vTime= $vidTime['contentDetails']['duration'];
    echo $vTime;
}
```

Now I need to detect when the iframe video ends. Do you have any idea how can I do that?
Thank you for any advice.